# How to get current date upto milliseconds using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, date

Is there any method provided by JavaScript to get the current date down to milliseconds? I am using `new Date()` method but this returns the time till seconds as follows:

```
console.log(new Date())
LOGS - Thu Sep 07 2017 14:47:37 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

What I need is like: `Thu Sep 07 2017 15:10:46:900100 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

However I need time up to milliseconds, that too upto 6 digits. Does JavaScript provide us any method to extract milliseconds? I know we can extract individual values like hours, minutes and milliseconds etc and append them again but that is not my requirement as **I need the date in default JavaScript DATE format** like mentioned above. So looking for any solutions related to that.

Comment: This https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_getmilliseconds.asp might be helpful.

Comment: Barely within 5 sec in first hit in google i got answer.

Comment: @TechnoCrat I just don't need the milliseconds, I need the complete clock as mentioned in the question.

Comment: If you need the specified format, you need to use any plugin or customize the date yourself

Comment: @Jonas Schafft has given answer, probably it might help you.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var now = new Date();  //Fri Jul 24 2020 11:41:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
   

var nowIso = now.toISOString(); //"2020-07-24T06:11:49.911Z"
   

var nowInMilliseconds = Date.parse(nowIso); //1595571109911
```

Comment: please format code as code .... and add some description to help **other** people to understand yout solution

Comment: Yes, I implemented your suggestion. Thanks. Also, the comments are examples of the output of each line.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code for your query :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
<p id="d"></p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds() + ":" + today.getMilliseconds();
    var dateTime = date+' '+time;
    alert(dateTime);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I know we can extract individuial values like hours, minutes and milliseconds etc and append them again but that is not my requirement as I need the date in default JS format like mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT

You can do this using the **momentJS**, you can donwload the JS from below link : https://momentjs.com/

```
var moment = require('moment');    
var momentDate = moment(date).format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:MM:ss:SSSSSSS Z");

Ti.API.info('momentDate ' + momentDate);
```

Hope this helps you better way, also have a look at the below link for more information about it.
https://momentjs.com/docs/

**Good Luck, Cheers**

Ashish Sebastian

Comment: I know we can extract individuial values like hours, minutes and milliseconds etc and append them again but that is not my requirement as I need the date in default JS format like mentioned above.

Comment: @Manu : I have updated the Answer please have a go through, let me know if this works and solves your problem

Comment: cant this be done with plain js without using moment?

Comment: Sorry boss, I guess not because the plain js Date object does not have the format method to Custom format the date Object.

Comment: The problem with using momentjs format method is that it returns date in string form, I need it as Date type.

Comment: @Manu : I don't understand your purpose to do so, can you add that to your question so that we can suggest accordingly. As it should be tough for anybody to answer the question with so many conditions in place, unless we understand the purpose of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153875/discussion-between-a-a-sebastian-and-manu).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMilliseconds();
```

If you want the full date:

```
var d = new Date();
var h = addZero(d.getHours(), 2);
var m = addZero(d.getMinutes(), 2);
var s = addZero(d.getSeconds(), 2);
var ms = addZero(d.getMilliseconds(), 3);
var fullDate = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + ":" + ms;

function addZero(x, n) {
    while (x.toString().length < n) {
        x = "0" + x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: I just don't need the milliseconds, I need the complete clock as mentioned in the question.

Comment: then you could just add them together? you can get everything from the date.

Comment: Where is `addZero` function ??

Comment: @Pugazh Right there! Lazy Copy Pasta ;-)

Comment: I know we can extract individual values like hours, minutes and milliseconds etc and append them again but that is not my requirement as I need the date in default JS format like mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

For microseconds, there is DOMHighResTimeStamp API ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp ) - try performance.now()

Answer (score 0):

Try below example. For complete reference check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Conversion_getter

```js
function addZero(v) {
  return (v < 10 ? v = '0' + v : v);
}

function getFullDate(dt) {
  var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  var mons = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

  var w = days[dt.getDay()];
  var M = mons[dt.getMonth()];
  var d = addZero(dt.getDate());
  var y = dt.getFullYear();
  var h = addZero(dt.getHours());
  var m = addZero(dt.getMinutes());
  var s = addZero(dt.getSeconds());
  var z = dt.getMilliseconds();
  if (z < 10)
    z = '00' + z;
  else if (z < 100)
    z = '0' + z;
  var fulldate = w + " " + M + " " + d + " " + y + " " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s + ":" + z;
  return fulldate;
}

console.log(getFullDate(new Date()));
```